# How to configure Maven pom for Tomcat 7 with JSF 2.0 and EL 2.2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jsf-2, el, tomcat7

i want to use **EL 2.2** for **JSF 2** application
and **tomcat 7** is provided with EL 2.2
and i am confused about the following:

1- Should i provide the **servlet-api**, **jsp-api** and the **EL** in my **pom** file (using maven) as **provided** or don't include them at all in the pom file, since they are provided by container, what's the difference ?

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>


        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
         <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.2</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
```

2- are they any required libraries to be added to pom file to be able to use EL 2.2 ?

3- Is there's any additional configuration needed in **web.xml** as in this article:

http://code2inspire.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/how-to-enable-el-2-2-on-tomcat-6/

please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One does not need to include in the pom.xml file as tomcat already has it. But in my experience, the needs arise to include the servlet-api dependency in the pom when i try to do some servlet programming. And like you said, define the scope as provided since it's already in the tomcat, and you dont want the servlet-api jar from pom to be included when building the war. My 2 cents is not to include the dependency as long as it's running, and include when the needs arise, and then document in the pom.xml the reason it's included.
2. I dont think you need to declare any other dependencies, as long as your container has the implementation already. I assume tomcat 7 does, since i'm using it also, and i dont declare anything else in pom dependency in order to make use of EL 2.x
3. Never tried it since im using t7, but crosschecking with the core jsf 3rd edition book, yeah, that'd work

Comment: My question is mostly architectural than anything. My code doesn't work with the el-api.jar (that comes as default in tomcat lib) and needs el-api-2.2.jar. #1. Does it make sense to add it in pom.xml? #2. Would the libraries interfere in any way if added in pom.xml? #3. Should I just replace the el-api.jar with the latest version, now v2.2?

Comment: @Dexter: #1 : i think it makes sense of course when you make use of the EL API  in your code, just as you only need to include servlet-api in your classpath when you want to do servlet programming in your code. #2 : when you use 'provided' scope for that artifact, then it will not interfere with the tomcat's EL api, since the jar will not be included in your WAR. #3 : if you're using tomcat 6, then yes. follow the instructions in http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/HowToEnableEl22