# Tomcat and JSF: EL Expression returns null

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2

I have the following problem: I have a webapplication using JSF 2 for the frontend. Until now the project and the deployment (using Tomcat 7) was configured just from eclipse. Everything worked fine.
Now i built the project using maven. The result in the war file is exactly the same as the output from eclipse (diff says that there is no difference). Ok, and now i would like to deploy the war file using (the same) tomcat without eclipse. The startup of the application works fine, but as soon as I visit the first jsf page some errors occur. It seems as if the webapplication is not able to resolve the el expressions (but there is no exception that would indicate that el-api is not found for example). From what I can see in the log files null is returned all the times from the el expressions.
Since there is no difference in the results of the build process using maven or eclipse the error should be in the configuration of tomcat.
Any hints?

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using ?
Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794794/how-to-configure-maven-pom-for-tomcat-7-with-jsf-2-0-and-el-2-2

Comment: Tomcat is version 7. servlet-api and el-api is set to provided like in the suggested link.

Comment: Is Java that starts tomcat in both situation is the same?

Comment: What is the exception that is listed in your Tomcat log when you refresh or launch the page?

Comment: Yes, in both situations oracle java version 1.6.0_38. I already thought that it could be because of incompatibilities between java 6 and tomcat 7, but then the problem would also exist with eclipse.

Comment: velo: there is no excption that would indicate a problem resolving the EL. There are just exceptions that result from the null that is returned by the EL:

"locale="#{languageProviderBean.recentLocale}" returned null"

and

"Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-" library"

The primefaces theme is specified in web.xml. If i remove the EL from the web.xml and set a theme directly the theme works.

Comment: Ok, my fault. There is a difference between the build results from maven and eclipse. The class files are the same, but many differ a little bit in the size, just some bytes. How is this possible? Both definitely use java 6. The Eclipse build result works, the maven build result not (both deployed with tomcat without eclipse).